# Possible to install a package without installing dependencies?

Tags: r

Is it possible to install a package without installing dependencies?

When run the following command:

```
install.packages("package",dependencies=FALSE)
```

if the dependencies are not installed beforehand, isn't it that the installation of the package fails?

My question comes from this post [Install a local R package with dependencies from CRAN mirror](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25017195/156458). Why does it  say installing a local package without installing dependencies?

> if I set repos=NULL it correctly tries to install the local package
>   file (as documented), but obviously it does not find the dependencies
>   packages.

Thanks!

Comment: you might say more about what you're trying to achieve.  One possibility (not easy) would be to download the package source and edit out the stuff that depends on the dependencies so that you can use the rest of it ...

Comment: @Ben: I am not achieving anything. When I read that post, I wonder why it is possible to install a pacakge without installing its dependencies.

Comment: OK, then you got your answer ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You cannot install and get a package to work without its dependencies. The `dependencies=` parameter is really an indicator if you would like R to *automatically* install the dependencies. If set to FALSE, R still stop and warn you so you can decide what you would like to do; if TRUE, R will automatically try to download from your current CRAN repository mirror. With `repos=NULL` (a local file install) there is nowhere else to look for dependencies so the `dependencies=` parameter is ignored.